# Error in sending email while registering the user

Tags: python, django, email

I'm trying to send the email when the user register but it just redirect to the expected page but without sending the email.

Here is my code

```
def register_view(request):  # Creates a New Account & login New users
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/")

    else:
        title = "Register"
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            # new_user = authenticate(email=user.email, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/books")

            subject = "Greetings"
            msg = "Congratulations Yor Account is created Successfully. Do not share your login credentials with anyone else"
            to = "Ak4695755@gmail.com"
            res = send_mail(subject, msg, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [to])

        context = {"title": title, "form": form}
        return render(request, "accounts/signup.html", context)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: And? You forget to type the problem you are facing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are return redirect before the message is sent, the rest of the `if form.is_valid()` statement is executed:

```py
if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        # new_user = authenticate(email=user.email, password=password)
        login(request, user)

        subject = "Greetings"
        msg = "Congratulations Yor Account is created Successfully. Do not share your login credentials with anyone else"
        to = "Ak4695755@gmail.com"
        res = send_mail(subject, msg, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [to])

        return redirect("/books")
   ...
```